# Mapping values in one DataFrame based on the data from external data table

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have DF as below of actual features' values (more than 6000 rows):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | acc | ? |
| 2 | B | bcc | ? |
| 5 | T | aoo | ? |
| 1 | V | mlo | ? |
| 5 | C | aeo | ? |
| 3 | A | aoo | ? |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

and I need to match output value D from DF according to data table below (DT) (less than 50 rows):

| A min | A max | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | A | acc | 120 |
| 1 | 5 | T | bcc | 131 |
| 2 | 3 | A | bcc | 129 |
| 2 | 3 | B | aoo | 134 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

each row in DF should have some D even if there is no exact match in DT (the closest one from DT or a mean from D values in DT if several rows match the given row from DF). Is there any clean approach to map those values?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `merge` then filter with range

```
out = df1.merge(df2,on=['B','C'],how='left')
out = out[(out['A']>=out['A min']) & (out['A']<=out['A max'])]
out
Out[421]: 
   A  B    C  Amin  Amax      D
0  1  A  acc   1.0   5.0  120.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It partially solves my problem, left merge returns more rows than df1 has which is fine, I can count a mean of D value from duplicates. But a problem is with filtering. The filter returns only 1500 rows from df1 of 6000 rows because there is a lot of A values in 'out' that don't fit the condition in line 2. But I can imagine it is necessary to write a function to avoid the above issue. Again thanks!